# SetInterval function not triggering in for loop (nodejs, express, socket.io)

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, socket.io, setinterval

I have a function called when a game starts. "lobby.players" is an object with 2 socket objects inside. I've assigned setInterval to the update variable of each player (socket) object. But the interval only runs for one of them (the second one).

```
function startGame(lobby) {
        for (var i in lobby.players) {
            console.log(lobby.players[i].id)
            lobby.players[i].emit('startGame', {
                map: lobby.map,
            });
            lobby.players[i].update = setInterval(function() {
                lobby.players[i].emit('update', getUpdatePackage(lobby));
                console.log("update " + lobby.players[i].id)
            }, 1000 / gameConfig.FPS)
            console.log(lobby.players[i].update)
        }
        console.log("Game in lobby " + lobby.id + " is starting.")
    
    }
```

I've added some console.log() lines so that you can see what I mean and this is the output:
[image]

It seems like the "update" variable is getting overwritten but it doesn't seem possible to me with the "i" changing as it should. I have no idea if this can be caused by something outside of the function. If it can I can add more snippets. Thank you for any explanation.

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var` in your `for` loop. With `var`, there's only one `i` in the function. With `let`, each iteration of the loop has its own `i`.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. Although I've looked into it and being new to js I can't really say I understand why the var wouldn't work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @MartinBrůžek if you use `let`, each iteration creates a new scope with new variables, if you use `var` the same variable is reused. So actually all intervals run, but using the wrong variables, all of them use the variables as they are after they are updated again in the very last iteration of the loop.

Comment: @Krokodil Wouldn't the same thing apply for all for loops using var? Why is setInterval different? As far as I know all my other for loops are working as intended

Comment: @MartinBrůžek yes, the same thing is true for all loops using `var`, but it only matters when you "capture" the loop variable in something like your `setInterval()` callback function.

Answer (score 2):

Pointy pointed out:
Use let instead of var in your for loop. With var, there's only one i in the function. With let, each iteration of the loop has its own i.